# Null value property with nHibernate inside class?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, properties

**Frecuencia.cs**

```
public class Frecuencia : Modelo<Frecuencia>
{
    ...
    public virtual string FrecuenciaEspecifica { get; set; }
    ...

    protected virtual FrecuenciaEspecifica GetFrecuenciaEspecifica()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FrecuenciaEspecifica);
    }
}
```

**frecuencia.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="Dominio"
                  namespace="Dominio">
  <class name="Frecuencia" table="frecuencias">
    ...
    <property name="FrecuenciaEspecifica" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If I call `GetFrecuenciaEspecifica()` I get an empty output but if I try: 
`Console.WriteLine(Frecuencia.FrecuenciaEspecifica)` inside **another** class, I get the output value.
See images below

### [image: image1]

[image: image2]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you are creating each instance, but given that you are using NHibernate, I'd guess that the first example, where it is null, is not being obtained from an `ISession`, or if you did, the session is closed, and the exception is being swallowed by WPF.

If it is not loaded from a session, then there is no proxy, and no mechanism to load the value from the database. You can check this by using the immediate window and type `this is NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy` and if the value is `false` then you didn't load it from a session.

If the session is closed, and WPF is swallowing it, you can use the Visual Studio Exceptions dialog to stop on `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: you are right! I check if there is no proxy and the value es false but I do not know how this happens...

Comment: The way it happens is that you call `new Frecuencia()` somewhere instead of calling `session.Get<Frecuencia>(id)`.

Comment: Also I have the other situation where the expression `this is NHibernate.Proxy.INHibernateProxy` is true but all properties are null.

Comment: I know but I'm not doing that explicitly.

Comment: You can see my app [here](http://code.google.com/p/tab-com/source/browse/). The main project is TableroComando

Comment: I'd like to help you more, but I can't spend so much time on this. I don't even have subversion installed. If you'd make it easier to diagnose, probably in a new question, I could probably help.

Comment: I rewrote this issue and I have been more clear in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353789/null-and-empty-values-property-from-inside-class-in-nhibernate), I guess